# Magit: How reset-soft to specific commit?

Tags: helm, magit

List of my branches:

- `develop`
- `features/magi`
- `master`

Current branch is `features/magi`.

I want to reset from current commit (**commit 3**) to previous commit (**commit 1**). So I use command:

```
magit-reset-soft
```

But Magit offers me to reset to one of the branches. Why?

Here screenshot:

[image: Magit-reset-soft]

[image: Magit guess]

Comment: Magit is offering some likely completion candidates for resetting to, but you are free to enter any branch/commit ref you like here, such as `@~2` (`HEAD` minus two commits).

Comment: Note that Magit will automagitally offer any branch/commit ref under point as the default completion candidate.

Comment: See also the Magit User Manual node on [Resetting](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Resetting.html).

Answer (score 3):

`magit-reset-soft` does not offer the hashes of all commits as completion candidates because there could be thousands. It does however offer branches as candidates because there usually are only a few dozens at most. It also offers either the hash of the commit at point or some "description". In your case after you have moved point into the `ac29adc * commit 1` line it would offer `feature/magi~2` as the *default* completion candidate.

I recommend you also read about [Completion and Confirmation](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Completion-and-Confirmation.html) in the Magit manual. (You might also want to read the other subnodes of [Interface Concepts](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Interface-Concepts.html).)